# SSRS Report runs slower in Preview Mode/Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and using Microsoft Reporting Services Projects Extension v2.6.7. The problem i am facing is i have a report that process about 60k records, the report is complex and has Groups, repeat headers, dataset filters and also VB Code.

The stored procedure used for this report runs in less than 10 seconds and when the report is deployed to Report Server the report completes rendering in less than 2 Mins. But when I run the same report using Visual Studio in preview or Run Mode (Report Viewer) the report runs for a whooping 17-20 mins. I have used SQL Profiler and see the Stored procedure execution time is almost same as the report execution time. The stored procedure is designed to handle parameter sniffing issue and I dont see any issue with the procedure.

From the report side, i have tried Keeptogether=false, Interactive size etc that could impact performance. They look fine.

I also tried to add WorkingSetMaximum to increase memory but still no luck. The client i am working with requires to have the RDLC File integrated in their app and will not want to deploy on Report Server for their own reason.

How can i make my report run faster in Visual Studio Preview Mode/Report Viewer (Run Mode) so that I can match the performance of the report with the performance i Get in Report Server.

Also if anyone could tell if there is a difference in how the report rendering works on Report Server vs Preview Mode.

Edit 1 -  Report Server and the database is configured in my laptop and it is not having any different configuration.

Edit 2 - Another observation i have gathered by running SQL Profiler is that during Preview mode the connection is kept open and the data retrieval time justifies report run time. Both are same. But when i run the report through report manager from the same machine, procedure completes in seconds and even the report renders faster. And As i have mentioned above, i have taken care of parameter sniffing. I am now trying to understand if there is a difference in the way SSRS Engine treats report rending and data retrieval for Preview and when report is deployed to reporting service.

Comment: When you render a report within Visual Studio, it's your local PC that is doing all the work. My guess would be that your PC's resources (CPU/Memory) are much lower that the server.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Report Server and the database is configured in my laptop and it is not having any different configuration.

Comment: Use the existing framework but force the use of Legacy CAS [code access security] Security
In Winforms <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
In ASP Net application <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/> Using this resolves the performance in RDLC File but performance of the report in visual studio still remains as a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this Q&A discussion in MSDN. I tried to replicate this and it gave me a fix by changing the trust level for CAS in config file. But still I have a question with regards to how Report Viewer in Visual Studio behaves. Is there any similar setting that we use in the application config that can be used to improve development and test performance in Visual Studio.

[MSDN Blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Use the existing framework but force the use of Legacy CAS [code access security] Security

1. In Winforms `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />`
2. In ASP Net application `<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>`